# How to creata column which will have trade type according values from other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create column 'Trade' which shows trade type according to Export_Value and Import_value columns. So if  `Import_value` is not equal to 0 then `'Trade' == Import`, while `Export_value` is not equal to 0 then `'Trade' == Export`. However, in this data frame, I have commodities that have both `Export_value` and `Import_value`. In such a case, I want to separate this row into two rows.
Finally, I want:
If data:

```
Product_name  Import value   Export_value 
Product X          1000         1000
Prduct Y             0           1000


Product_name  Import value   Export_value    Trade
Product X            0         1000           Export
Product X           1000        0             Import
Prduct Y             0          1000           Export
```

Comment: @Chris that is a good question. At first, I thought I will use the initial data then realized that it has too much information. Deleted.

Answer (score 0):

**Use:**

```
m = df[['Import value', 'Export_value']].ne(0).all(axis=1)

df1, df2 = df[m], df[m]
df1['Import value'], df2['Export_value'] = 0, 0

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df[~m]], ignore_index=True)
df3['Trade'] = np.select([df3['Import value'].ne(0), df3['Export_value'].ne(0)], ['Import', 'Export'])
```

**Details:**

Create a *boolean mask* `m` where all the values in both the columns `Import value` and `Export_value` are not equal to `0` this mask will be needed to replicate rows having both import and export values as `non zero`.

```
# print(m)
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Use *boolean masking* to create two new temporary dataframes from `df` and assign `Import value=0` to `df1` and `Export value=0` to `df2`

```
# print(df1)
  Product_name  Import value  Export_value
0    Product X             0          1000

# print(df2)
  Product_name  Import value  Export_value
0    Product X          1000             0
```

Using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concat the dataframes `df1`, `df2` and `df[~m]` along `axis=0`, finally use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to select the values from
choices `Import` and `Export` based on the conditions.

```
# print(df3)
  Product_name  Import value  Export_value   Trade
0    Product X             0          1000  Export
1    Product X          1000             0  Import
2     Prduct Y             0          1000  Export
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proc_df = df[(df['import'] > 0) & (df['export'] > 0)]
for i in range(0,len(proc_df)):
    dict = {'Product_name' : df['Product_name'][i], 'import' : 0, 'export' : df['export'][i]}
    df['export'][i] = 0
    df = df.append(dict, ignore_index=True)

for i in df['import']:
    if i == 0:
        df['trade'] = 'export'
```

I hope that this gives you an idea about how you need to do it